# Custom url in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to create url like ***{base_url}*/customize/*{product_slug}*.phtml**

Could please help how to make this of url Magento?

Currently I have created "**CustomizeController.php**" file

```
<?php
class ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_CustomizeController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction(){
        echo 'test mamethode';
        $product = Mage::getModel("productcustomizer/customizeproduct")->getProduct();
    }

    public function mamethodeAction(){
     echo 'test mamethode';
    }
}
```

and below code in **config.xml** file

```
<productcustomizer_customize_index>   
    <reference name="root">   
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>   
    </reference>   
    <reference name="content">   
        <block type="productcustomizer/customize" name="productcustomizer_customize" template="productcustomizer/customize.phtml"/>   
    </reference>   
</productcustomizer_customize_index>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please assign in $url_key to resolve the issue.

```
$rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite');
    $rewrite->setStoreId($store_id) ->setIdPath('customize/'.$url_key) ->setRequestPath('customize/'.$url_key.'.html') ->setTargetPath('customize/index/action/id/'.$url_key) ->setIsSystem(true) ->save();
```

Comment: Please put the given code into your custom module controller.

Ex. - public function mamethodeAction(){
        $rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite');
    $rewrite->setStoreId($store_id) ->setIdPath('customize/'.$url_key) ->setRequestPath('customize/'.$url_key.'.html') ->setTargetPath('customize/index/action/id/'.$url_key) ->setIsSystem(true) ->save();
      }

Comment: It is redirecting to the 404 page

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution you can set routing using **config.xml** file

```
<global>
        <rewrite>
            <productcustomizer_url>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/customize/#]]></from>
                <to><![CDATA[/productcustomizer/customize/index/product/]]></to>
                <complete>1</complete>
            </productcustomizer_url>
        </rewrite>
<global>
```